# Is there a name/literature for this variation of the projection matrix?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, terminology

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an $n \times m$ real matrix, and define the corresponding matrices:

$$\mathbf{P}_k(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-k} \mathbf{x}^\text{T}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for } k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

I already know that $\mathbf{P}_1(\mathbf{x})$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the column-space of $\mathbf{x}$.  For higher values of $k$ you are raising the inverse-Gramian matrix in the middle to a higher power, which means it is no longer a projection matrix, but it still gives you an $n \times n$ matrix.  Some of these matrices may be interesting in certain contexts (see below).

**My Question:** Are any of these matrices for $k \geqslant 2$ well-known?  Do they have names?  Are there any references to these matrices in the mathematical/statistical literature?

---

*Some context: I am interested in this because the matrix $\mathbf{P}_2(\mathbf{x})$ arises in regression analysis, through the fact the squared distance of the OLS estimator from the true coefficient --- i.e., we have $||\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} - \boldsymbol{\beta}||^2 =  \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^\text{T} \mathbf{P}_2(\mathbf{x}) \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$.  I'm wondering whether this matrix is a well-known form.*